# Find most recent record within 90 days from another table and return relevant columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a requirement to join two sets of data:

[image]

[image]

The first set of data shows me users who have visited within the previous month
The second set shows me all the visits in history for the users that visited in the first table

What i need to do is show all of the first set and then add in some information from the second set according to the following criteria

- Show all columns from second set if there has been a previous start/end period that has ended within 90 days of the start shown in the first set.
- If there has not been a visit 90 days prior to the start shown in the first set then do not return any extra columns from the second set

be aware that the second set of data contains the visit shown in the first set

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Any help would be most appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [INNER JOIN](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-inner-join/)

Comment: Sample data, DDL scripts, current output, and desired results will help slow folks like myself follow along better.

Comment: If you want to join images then you are not in the right forum. If you want to join data SETs then please provide queries to create the tables and to insert the sample data instead of images. **Thanks**